# URL is being Truncated

Tags: silverlight, url, hyperlink

We have a link in a silverlight application:

http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/ord?station:|slot:/Drivers/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx

When our client tries running the applicaiton it is supposed to access the link directly, however, it appears to be truncating the url to:

http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/

We are unable to reproduce the issue on our systems, but the person says he gets the same result on his work computer and his home computer. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a possible EBKAC problem (Error Between Keyboard And Chair) :)

You need to see exactly what this user is doing (cut & paste from multi-line links in emails can cause this sort of problem).

Comment: The link is embedded in the silverlight program. the User just logs in and presses enter. The hyperlink is never copied. We found out today that the user can access the program correctly while on his home network, but when he is on his work network, it will not work.

Comment: @Critter: That put a slightly different light on it. It is more likely their company firewall or router changes certain URLs. I notice your example has a pipe "|" symbol in it. Is that correct?